# CHKDSK is unable to fix NTFS errors

Tags: windows-7, boot, ntfs, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption

After my PC shutdown due to power failure, I noticed several errors in EventViewer.

> The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume \Device\HarddiskVolume2.

and

> The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume C:.

So I forced a chkdsk check at startup, and it finds a stream of error, [here is the output](http://pastebin.com/c1pw3De2), it is smaller than the actual log, because, Event Viewer only seems to have this much, the same line was repeated thousands of times.Here is that line.

```
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x4
in file 0x198f2 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 104690.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x0 is cross linked
```

Also, even after running CHKDSK, the same errors were being reported again so I ran CHKDSK **another time** and it still loops the same line above, without fixing the error.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Someone else has the same problem http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/166030-major-file-corruption-system-wide.html

Comment: right after you had the problem the 1st time, I would be moving the data all to a different disk item. Even an image made outside of the system with the freeware WDacronis could possibly still make an image file. After you secure the data, completly re-partition and reformat the drive, even check.clear the MBR, then test the disk with real data, and move it back again. I dont know what else to tell you.  Could be a hard failure, but it could also be some stupid mixup from a confusion. with some bootloader or partition table issue, or even a Block addressing thing.

Comment: For more information, could you tell what is the Disk size, what was the partition size, what other partitions? what was the file system, and everything about it, what is the boot stuff, and was it ACPI or not? What port is it on, on what type of controller chip? internal external, what bootloaders were used, what partitioning method was used?  what products do you use that do "offline" (at boot) activity to the drives?  Does the MBR fixes work properly or fail?

Comment: keep going, at a power fail, did the bios possibly reset?  (looking for the block translation issues)

Comment: Do you like to try it fixing by other software's or just you want it from `chkdsk`.

Comment: @Psycogeek Nope, no BIOS reset, 500 gig Seagate HDD, it is ACPI, it's in SATA0, Bootloader is grub, it boots fine, just these errors are thrown.

Comment: @Psycogeek http://superuser.com/a/415342/71027

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by running CHKDSK **4 times**, I allowed CHKDSK to run for four times, and then amazingly no errors !

Comment: I had a ntfs file system problem a while back, but not like yours, it took 4 rounds of chkdsk to fix it also. Making note of this, thanks for verifying this actually works for some problems.

Comment: @HackToHell - This likely indicates the fact, after each run, additional errors were created ( and/or there is an upper limit to the error detection ) both would make sense.  Since the hdd is likely failing in some matter, because of the power outage, the first is likely scenario.